# Prove that for two real numbers $a,b$, if for any $e>0$ they can be bounded by $s,s'$: $s'\geq a\geq s,s'\geq b\geq s$ and $s'-s<e$, then $a=b$.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I don't understand the proof of lemma presented in the title. I found it in the book "Differential and integral calculus" by G. M. Fichtenholz, it's lemma 2, section 2.8, chapter 1. I don't think this book was ever published in English, I'm using Polish version, so I will translate the original statement and proof. The lemma states: "Let $\alpha, \beta$ be real numbers. If for any number $e > 0$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be bounded by the same rational numbers $s, s'$,
$$s' \geq \alpha \geq s,\quad s' \geq \beta \geq s,$$
with a difference less than $e$,
$$s' - s < e,$$ then $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must be equal.

The lemma will be proved by reduction to absurdity. Let $\alpha > \beta$. We can put two rational numbers  $r, r'$ between $\alpha$ and $\beta$(this was stated and proved in another lemma),
$$\alpha > r' > r > \beta.$$
Then for any $s', s$, between which are $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
$$s' > r' > r > s, \quad s' - s > r' - r > 0,$$
so $s' - s$, contrary to lemma assumptions, can't be smaller than $e = r' - r$. This contradiction proves correctness of the lemma."

I don't understand the idea of this proof. I think that in proofs by contradiction, one has to assume the proposition to be false which leads to contradiction. I don't see such assumption there. Personally I belive that the only thing that was proved, was that necessary conditions of the lemma weren't met. If it indeed is a valid proof, please explain it to me, how from the given statements it follows that $\alpha = \beta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give two propositions $P,Q$, the statement $P\rightarrow Q$ is equivalent to $\neg Q \rightarrow \neg P$. This means that it's equivalent to prove:

- if $P$ is true, then $Q$ is true
- if $Q$ is false, then $P$ is false

On your lemma, you can identify $P$ as "for any two real numbers [...] and $s-s'<e$" and $Q$ as $a=b$. Then, proving that lemma is equivalent to proving that that whenever $\alpha\neq \beta$ ($Q$ is false), we can find two real numbers and $e>0$ such that for every $s,s'$ verifying $s'\geq \alpha\geq s$ and $s'\geq \beta \geq s$, it must be $s-s'>e$ ($P$ is false).

Then, let's assume that $\alpha\neq\beta$. Because $\mathbb{R}$ is a totally ordered field, either $\alpha>\beta$ or $\alpha<\beta$. We can assume without loss of generality that $\alpha>\beta$; because if $\alpha<\beta$, the proof would be the same by just "exchanging" the variables $\alpha$ and $\beta$. The proof you posted starts from here on.

PS: I don't really know if you needed this much information, if this wasn't really your question or if it's ok. Let me know if there is something else.